# Why are my locations undefined and display not updating?

Tags: javascript, html, prototype, case

I am having some issues with a class project. Every thing was working fine and dandy up until the current part we are on. Basically, we had to add prototypes and cases to move to each location. Now my code will not work, and the teacher is about as helpful as a pet rock. I have two parts to my code, the html (which has part of the code including items and such) and the .js file that includes the locations.

I have created a repository on Github so it is easily accessible to all who want to help. At this point it is too late to submit to my professor, but I am curious on what I did wrong.

https://github.com/EmeraldX/Project-Help/tree/master

The main and directions.js are the files that I am currently working with.

Thanks!

Update: Okay, so it's still not working, and when I use Chrome's console it just tells me that:

`function updateDisplay( message ) {
        var textArea = document.getElementById("introduction");
        textArea.value = message + "\n\n" + textArea.value;`

Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, we don't want to comb through your whole Git respository trying to find your bug.

Comment: You also need to be more specific than "does not work". What is it supposed to do, what does it do instead?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/x5wyv9ws/ -  missing bracket at the end of lines with new Item such as `locations[2] = new Location(2,"Lake","A large lake that is formed by a river flowing from the East.", new Item(1,"Fish","An old rotting fish.");` and you need to load directions.js after Item has been defined

Comment: A good IDE is going to help you spot syntax errors that could otherwise cost you hours of time.

Comment: @WalkerBoh what is an IDE? I apologize I am only in introductory programming and the professor is terrible at teaching anything to us so it is very touch and go.

Comment: It's no problem. An IDE is 'integrated development environment'. They are high-end text editors specifically built for coding. There are hundreds of IDEs out there, all for different programming languages. I personally work with phpstorm. It's a great IDE that is compatible with many languages including php, javascript, html, sql, html and more. You need to buy a license for it (or google a license, people put their own out there for free). My previous IDE was Geany which is a very good, fast and lightweight IDE and free. Make sure you look up a tutorial for the IDE you choose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried opening your html page and js using firefox, and used the firebug consol to see if anything was wrong.

It looks like you have an `)` missing in your js:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list directions.js:7:145

And it was right:

```
locations[2] = new Location(2,"Lake","A large lake that is formed by a river flowing from the East.", 
                                new Item(1,"Fish","An old rotting fish.");
```

is missing a ')'

After correcting it, it appear that you miss this `)` line 7, 9, 13 and 14.

Then a new error pop up:

> ReferenceError: Item is not defined directions.js:7:2

This can be corrected by calling your `direction.js` AFTER you js script in `main.html`.

Hope it can help